# How to make object move but stay within another object?

Tags: animation

I want to make my donut drop, and at the center of donut there is a cylinder. I want to make it so when the donuts drop, they don't go off from the cylinder.

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the images, the donut is not in the same position on the cylinder anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Have you applied a passive rigid body to the cylinder? This hould solve the problem

Comment: thank you for the replied jonas, its really help so i figure it out, this one need another silinder again so my donut wont throw away randomly :") , coz when i try using a passive rigid to the main cilinder my donut went away randomly,

thankyou for your advicee it work pretty damn well

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need to setup:

1. all the involved objects (plane, cylinder, toruses) must have rigid body enabled (to calculate gravity and collisions)
2. plane and cylinder must be passive, toruses active (they're moving)
3. all involved objects MUST have all transform applied

Plus, all objects (except plane perhaps) need to have the 'mesh' shape type setting, as shown in the picture. When you need to precisely evaluate complex geometries this is the best setting.

example:

[image]

then play the animation to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Choosing collision on the cylinder will not do anything. Instead you will need to set it as a rigid body, but then change it from type `active` to `passive`.

Comment: yes, i try the collision cuz im already give up and try randomly thing to make this work, it work perfectly as i want it now 

thank you for the replieed

Comment: You are welcome! If you'd like, it is also possible to mark a solution as "accepted" so other people viewing this question will know what worked for you.